# Need to generate different random numbers everytime the loop runs

Tags: python, numpy, random

I need to generate a different set of random numbers inside the second for loop. But everytime the second for loop runs, it generates same set of random numbers.

```
class pricing_lookback:
  def __init__(self,spot,rate,sigma,time,sims,steps):
    self.spot = spot
    self.rate = rate
    self.sigma = sigma
    self.time = time
    self.sims = sims
    self.steps = steps
    self.dt = self.time/self.steps

  def call_floatingstrike(self):
      pathwiseminS = np.array([])
      simulationS = np.array([])
      simulationSt = np.array([])
      call2 = np.array([])
      tst1 = np.array([])
      for j in range(self.sims):
          sT = self.spot
          for i in range(self.steps):
              phi= np.random.rand()
              sT *= np.exp((self.rate-0.5*self.sigma*self.sigma)*self.dt + self.sigma*phi*np.sqrt(self.dt))
              pathwiseminS = np.append(pathwiseminS, sT)
          tst1 = np.append(tst1, pathwiseminS[1])
          call2 = np.append(call2, np.max((pathwiseminS[self.steps-1]-self.spot),0))
          simulationSt = np.append(simulationS,pathwiseminS[self.steps-1])
          simulationS =  np.append(simulationS,min(pathwiseminS))

      call = np.average(simulationSt) - np.average(simulationS)

      return call,call2, tst1

pricelookback = pricing_lookback(110,0.05,0.2,1,200,252)
clookback, call2, t1 = pricelookback.call_floatingstrike()


print(clookback,t1)
```

Comment: After running your code, the only "random" line is `phi = np.random.rand()`, and it produces a different value every time when run, I think your error is somewhere else.  My first guess is you are just appending the same value over and over to your output list

Comment: No everytime the loop starts it starts generating same set of Random numbers. So I have 200 scenarios and 252 time points in each. Every scenario has same set of random numbers in the same sequence.

Comment: if that's the case, you need a call to np.random.seed()

Comment: @TomLubenow I am not sure how use it in this case. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: Computers can't be random. They are deterministic machines because we don't know how to build them any other way. As a result, they can't actually create random numbers, all "random" numbers are actually pseudo-random. There is a lot to read about this, if you look up pseudo-random number generators. In short, you'll keep getting the same sequence of seemingly random numbers (because they aren't actually random) unless you "seed" your random number generator. Numpy has a function for this: np.random.seed().

Comment: I can't test if this fixes your problem because your code almost certainly has a bug as @user3483203 pointed out.

Comment: `phi= np.random.rand()` is doing its job correctly in your code, the problem is somewhere else as suggested by @TomLubenow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @user3483203 pointed out, your error is somewhere else. All the variables are randomized in your second for loop: the variable `phi` and `sT` is random each loop. You are appending `pathwiseminS[1]` (constant, non-randomized value) to `tst1` or `t1` each time which is the first element, or first loop value of `sT`. You should trying refreshing/emptying the `pathwiseminS` (as I think this is what you're trying to do), like this:

```
def call_floatingstrike(self):
      simulationS = np.array([])
      simulationSt = np.array([])
      call2 = np.array([])
      tst1 = []
      for j in range(self.sims):
          sT = self.spot
          pathwiseminS = np.array([]) #notice the placement here
          for i in range(self.steps):
              phi= np.random.rand()
              sT *= np.exp((self.rate-0.5*self.sigma*self.sigma)*self.dt + self.sigma*phi*np.sqrt(self.dt))
              pathwiseminS = np.append(pathwiseminS, sT)
          tst1 = np.append(tst1, pathwiseminS[1])
          call2 = np.append(call2, np.max((pathwiseminS[self.steps-1]-self.spot),0))
          simulationSt = np.append(simulationS,pathwiseminS[self.steps-1])
          simulationS =  np.append(simulationS,min(pathwiseminS))

      call = np.average(simulationSt) - np.average(simulationS)

      return call,call2, tst1
```

Comment: That works but quite strange why it does that! Thank you very much, greatly appreciate it.